# How could I fix this torch.zero() problem?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to write a Logistic Regression by myself, but I found an error while initializing this torch.zero().

code：

```py
w = torch.normal(0, 0.01, size=(2,1), requires_grad=True)
b = torch.zeros(1,require_grad=True) # Error occured here
```

Error message：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linearRegression.py", line 37, in <module>
    b = torch.zeros(1,require_grad=True)
TypeError: zeros() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (int, require_grad=bool), but expected one of:
 * (tuple of ints size, *, tuple of names names, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
 * (tuple of ints size, *, Tensor out, torch.dtype dtype, torch.layout layout, torch.device device, bool pin_memory, bool requires_grad)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, change `require_grad` to `requires_grad`.